# ORC to CSV convertion

Tags: csv, orc

I have data in Hive and underneath files are stored in .orc format.  i don't want to query Hive to export data to .csv.  So looking for alternate approaches directly converting .orc extension files in background to .csv files.  is there a tool or jar process available to do that ?

Appreciate your attention.

Comment: Spark has its own ORC library. But I don't get what you mean by _"in background"_.

Comment: Samson!  Data stores as ORC files in HDFS.  instead of querying Hive to get data, we would like to read ORC from HDFS and convert it to CSV.

Comment: Without hive, you might be interested in [How can I convert local ORC files to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54482815/562769)