# How can I convert local ORC files to CSV?

Tags: csv, orc

I have an ORC file on my local machine and I need any reasonable format from it (e.g. CSV, JSON, YAML, ...).

How can I convert ORC to CSV?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. [Download](https://orc.apache.org/docs/java-tools.html)
2. Extract the files, go to the `java` folder and execute maven: `mvn install`
3. Use ORC-Tools

This is how I use them - you will likely need to adjust the paths:

```
java -jar ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/orc/orc-tools/1.5.4/orc-tools-1.5.4-uber.jar data ~/your_file.orc > output.json
```

The output is [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/) which is easy to convert to CSV. First I needed to remove the last two lines from the output. Then:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('output.json', lines=True)
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: Better download link: https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/orc

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be [bigdata-file-viewer](https://github.com/Eugene-Mark/bigdata-file-viewer), it's a cross-platform application. You can open an ORC file and save the file in CSV format.

The detailed usage is as following:

- Download runnable jar from release page or follow Build section to build from source code.
- Invoke it by java -jar BigdataFileViewer-1.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
- Open binary format file by "File" -> "Open". Currently, it can open file with parquet suffix, orc suffix and avro suffix. If no suffix specified, the tool will try to extract it as Parquet file
- Set the maximum rows of each page by "View" -> Input maximum row number -> "Go"
- Set visible properties by "View" -> "Add/Remove Properties"
- Convert to CSV file by "File" -> "Save as" -> "CSV"
- Check schema information by unfolding "Schema Information" panel